# What is a good resource for help on codes to use for App?

Tags: java, android

I am a novice programmer when it comes to Java, I have Java:How To Program 7th Ed. that I am reading. My major is Computer Science so I have a little bit of knowledge about what yo do but as for the Application. I am trying to make a game app and was wandering what would be a good source to reference for various things inside of the app mainly the game play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a very experienced programmer myself, but a general good idea is to read the Framework Topics in the Dev Guide on d.android.com completely. It gives a good view of what is possible within Android. 
It's not a complete guide on how-to though, but it's good to see what Android is capable of before you start anything.

Plus indeed the online tutorials, but be careful as there are also a lot of tutorials for older versions of Android, which sometimes have deprecated stuff in them. And sometimes I found some tutorials which were simply wrong and had a lot of errors in them, so it's always a good idea to look at the comments on the article. But this is general internet knowledge ;)

Plus there are some books especially about Game development for Android. 
(Beginning Android Games by Mario Zechner, for instance. I don't have the book but the title seems like something you need ;) )

If you want, you can also use adobe AIR to develop games for newer versions of Android.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner, you should not directly jump to game programming. You should first work on some Hello Wrold type programs. Go thorough the online tutorials. A lots of excellent material is available for free on internet. Best Luck.